# How to use cryptojs aes decrypt from java code with iv param and SecretKeySpec

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

From java code I have a code:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
byte[] keys = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptionKey);
SecretKey speckey = new SecretKeySpec(keys, "AES");
byte[] ivParam = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
System.arraycopy(speckey.getEncoded(), 0, ivParam, 0, ivParam.length);
cipher.init(cipherMode, speckey, new IvParameterSpec(ivParam));
return cipher;
```

In javascript I have a script to decrypt but it doesn't work:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  })
  console.log("Decrypted: ", decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

I know we need to parse iv(Like this `var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(pass);` but it doesn't work), key and maybe encrypted first to rub decrypted but I don't know with the Java code above How we can parse iv and key to decrypted. Who has worked in this please help me. Thanks so much <3

Comment: Explain what you mean whenever you write "doesn't work"

Comment: I don' t even see you *trying* to decode the key from base 64 or to derive the IV from it.

Comment: I'm just ask about what will we do with javascript use CryptoJS to decrypt a value if it's above java code, and in block javascript code just a sample(sorry that).
We need get key and ivParam right the way first then we can use CryptoJS.AES.decrypt to decrypt. but I don't know the way to get the key was SecretKey as java code and iv param